# Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to create an particle slider and there I got this error Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null I've looked in SO and there I came to know it's because my script is executing before page load but looks like it's not the case. here please any insight from you people?
Thank you :)

```
<script>
    let body = document.querySelector('body');
    body.id = 'logos';
    let init = () => {
        var myPS = new ParticleSlider({
            slideDelay: 10,
            mouseForce: 1000,
            monochrome: false,
            //showArrowControls: true,
            ptlGap: 5,
            ptlSize: 2,
            arrowPadding: 15,
            sliderId: 'logos',
        });
        (window.addEventListener
                ? window.addEventListener('click', function () {
            myPS.init(true)
        }, false)
                : window.onclick = function () {
            myPS.init(true)
        });
        window.onresize = () => {
            myPS.width = window.innerWidth;
            myPS.height = window.innerHeight;
        }
    }
    window.onload = init;
</script>
</head>
<body id="logos">
<div class="slides">
<div id="first-slide" class="slide" data-src="https://www.brandsoftheworld.com/sites/default/files/styles/logo-thumbnail/public/0020/5527/brand.gif?itok=SOQ1ZybO">
</div>
</div>
<canvas class="draw"></canvas>
<script src="js/particleSlider.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are `myPS` and `ps` supposed to be the same variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you explicitly set the `sliderId` to `logos` hence, your `body` tag must have that same *id*
also you need to put your script just before the end of your `body` tag.

```
<body id="logos">
   .......
   .......
</body>
```

or, you can also set it using *javascript* before initiating the particle

```
let body = document.querySelector('body');
body.id = 'logos';
```

Comment: what I want to add it with bootstrap for a responsive site development then how to use this?

Comment: @BhavikBamania also it should be `myPS.init()` not `ps.init()`

Comment: nup bro same issue with the updated answer should edit my question with the updated code for better insight?

Comment: hm.. you'd have to place your *script* before closing the `body` tag